# Regexp to match prompt in pxssh

Tags: python, prompt, pxssh

I am using `pxssh` in `Python3.6` to play with SSH by doing a script.

Everything works fine but I just have one little issue.

The prompt on the machine I'm logging on SSH change according to some commands I'm sending (not all!)

Here is the code of my script

```
from pexpect import pxssh
from codecs import encode

ip = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
username = 'user'
password = 'pass'
prompt = 'Something # '

s = pxssh.pxssh()

def send_cmd(s, cmd):
    "A simple generic function to send a command via SSH and printing it's result"
    s.sendline(cmd)
    s.prompt(timeout=1)
    print('*'*20)
    print((s.before).decode("utf-8"))
    return

if not s.login (ip, username, password, auto_prompt_reset=False):
    print('SSH session failed on login')
    print(str(s))
else:
    print('SSH session login successful')
    s.PROMPT = prompt
    send_cmd(s, 'commands')
    send_cmd(s, 'end')
    s.logout()
    print('Logged out of SSH session')
```

Here are some examples of prompts : 

`Something #
Something (toto) #
Something (tata) #
Something (...) #`

So I was wondering if it was possible to do a regexp to match this so that when I call `s.before`, I won't get the prompt.

I know that in Ruby I could do something like this

`(Something \(.+\)# )`

Is Python and/or pxssh supporting this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems a simple :

```
prompt = r'(Something .+ # )'
```

instead of :

```
prompt = 'Something # '
```

is enough.

Should have tried it earlier.. :)